# typescript-vim throws syntax error for flavored strings that actually compile fine

Tags: typescript, types, vim

Cross post from https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim/issues/201 but im not super optimistic of getting a quick response there.

In our code base we use Flavoring: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/
This allows us to name our string types, e.g.

```
type Flavoring<FlavorT> = { _type?: FlavorT; }
type Flavor<T, FlavorT> = T & Flavoring<FlavorT>;
...
type URL = Flavor<string, "URL">
type FooKey = Flavor<string, "FooKey">
```

now, these types are still just type `string`, so you can do all of the usual string indexing on dictionaries. For example:

```
const dict = { ... }
const key: FooKey = 'hello'
dict[key]
```

and typescript compiles just fine and there are no warnings.

But typescript-vim complains:
`Element implicitly has any type because expression FooKey cannot be used to index type {}`

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The plugin itself doesn't complain, it merely relays `tsc`'s complaint to you. If you are using `tsc` to compile your project and you are getting different outputs then you should investigate how it is invoked. If you are not using `tsc` to compile your project, then you might consider telling the plugin to use your compiler. Either way, the issue tracker is the perfect place for such questions.

Comment: At the top of this SO post I indicated that this is a cross post from the typecript-vim repo. Note however that the last time an issue was responded to there was 2 years ago, so...not hopeful of a response.

I don't have a global tsc install so I am suspicious that this is just 'relaying tsc's complaints'. Note that when I run the :make command in vim, it fails with 'tsc: command not found'

Comment: Then that plugin has nothing to with your problem because all it does is setting makeprg. And vim is unrelated too because it won't compile or check your code on its own. It simply doesn't know how to do it. Do you have ale installed?

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Even though I was able to disable the errors by disabling typescript-vim, as @romainl pointed out that particular plugin is dependent on the tsserver that is running. I had YouCompleteMe running as well, and YCM was using an old tsserver version. Updating the YCM server fixed my problems.

Thanks for your patience romainl!